# how to pass a string value from one .m file to another .m file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

Hi i am new to objective c. i have a .m file in which i have the string to be passed.

```
NSString *passedMonth;
```

i am Passing it like this

```
KLTile *kltil = [[KLTile alloc] inittempMonth:passedMonth];
```

temp month is string in other .m file

```
-(id)inittempMonth:(NSString *)tem{

        tempMonth = [[NSString alloc]init];
        self.tempMonth = tem;
        NSLog(@" temp month....%@",self.tempMonth);

    return self;
}
```

the log inside the init is giving the output but the same log outside the init method doe't works......

i want to use the tempMonth string outside the `-(id)inittempMonth:(NSString *)tem{`...
is there any way to use the string outside the init method...

Comment: You just need to declare one NSString variable in the KLTile.h and assign the passedMonth variable value in to it, you will be able to access the value in the whole page.

Comment: what does the tempMonth property declaration look like?

Comment: what you are doing is creating a special initializer, but this is not required to pass a string, did you mean to ask, how can I create an object with specific settings that I set when I create the object?

Comment: You need to stop and take a few steps back. Read up on the basics first. Make sure you read the documentation and don't just try to learn from snippets of code. Apple provide some excellent objective-c tutorials.

Comment: @Kuldeep .. I declared the variable and set the property for the string... but can't access it....

Comment: borrrden... i declare it strong as i am using ARC... @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tempMonth;

Answer (score 3):

Your `init` method is wrong. So you should modify it into something like:

```
- (id)initWithTempMonth:(NSString *)tem{
{
    self = [super init]; // This line is important
    if (self) {
        self.tempMonth = tem;
        NSLog(@" temp month....%@",self.tempMonth);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, don't forget to declare `tempMonth` as a retained property in the `.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tempMonth;
```

Or if you are using ARC:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tempMonth;
```

Then you can log the value of the property like this:

```
KLTile *kltil = [[KLTile alloc] inittempMonth:passedMonth];
NSLog(@"Temp month: %@", kltil.tempMonth);
```

---

Comment: I have declared the @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tempMonth; when i write this "self = [super init]; // This line is important" it shows can't assign to self outside the  method in the init family...one more thing is i want use the tempMonth string in the m file where initWithTempMonth:(NSString *)tem... medhod is writen...

Comment: I solved it by global declaring another string in .m file and passing the tempMonth to the global declared string. Like monthID = tempMonth; and use the global decalred string out side the method..

Comment: @vamsi575kg You need to stop and go back to basics. Using global variables for things like this is very bad.